# In spectrum color picker color pallete is showing on doubleclick for first time

Tags: jquery

I am using spectrum color picker for showing color pallete. But color pallete is showing on double click of input text box, but I need only for single click

```
$scope.clickColorPickerForStripedLines = function (id) {
    try {
        CheckSession1($http);
        var colorcode = $("#"+id).css('background-color');
        var newColor;
        $("#" + id).spectrum({
            showPaletteOnly: true,
            togglePaletteOnly: true,
            togglePaletteMoreText: 'more',
            togglePaletteLessText: 'less',
            color: colorcode,
            change: function (color) {
                newColor = color.toHexString();
                $("#" + id).parent().css('background-color', newColor);
                       PlotGraph($scope)
            },
            palette: [
                ["#000", "#444", "#666", "#999", "#ccc", "#eee", "#f3f3f3", "#fff"],
                ["#f00", "#f90", "#ff0", "#0f0", "#0ff", "#00f", "#90f", "#f0f"],
                ["#f4cccc", "#fce5cd", "#fff2cc", "#d9ead3", "#d0e0e3", "#cfe2f3", "#d9d2e9", "#ead1dc"],
                ["#ea9999", "#f9cb9c", "#ffe599", "#b6d7a8", "#a2c4c9", "#9fc5e8", "#b4a7d6", "#d5a6bd"],
                ["#e06666", "#f6b26b", "#ffd966", "#93c47d", "#76a5af", "#6fa8dc", "#8e7cc3", "#c27ba0"],
                ["#c00", "#e69138", "#f1c232", "#6aa84f", "#45818e", "#3d85c6", "#674ea7", "#a64d79"],
                ["#900", "#b45f06", "#bf9000", "#38761d", "#134f5c", "#0b5394", "#351c75", "#741b47"],
                ["#600", "#783f04", "#7f6000", "#274e13", "#0c343d", "#073763", "#20124d", "#4c1130"]
            ]
        });
        $('.sp-container').addClass('BgColorHeader PopupBorder');

    } catch (e) {
        WriteLogFile1('', _pageName, '$scope.clickColorPicker', e.description);
    }
}
```

and my html code is

```
<div  data-ng-click="clickColorPickerForStripedLines('MaxStripLineColor')" style="float:none;margin-left:127px;cursor:pointer;background-color:#74b9ff" class="AppendYAxisList_4">
  <input id="MaxStripLineColor" ng-model="MaxStripLineColor"   title={{MaxStripLineColor}} type="text" class="ColorAxisLabeltextbox" style="display:none;background-color:#74b9ff">
</div>
```

Comment: my html code is <div  data-ng-click="clickColorPickerForStripedLines('MaxStripLineColor')" style="float:none;margin-left:127px;cursor:pointer;background-color:#74b9ff" class="AppendYAxisList_4">

Comment: <input id="MaxStripLineColor" ng-model="MaxStripLineColor"   title={{MaxStripLineColor}} type="text" class="ColorAxisLabeltextbox" style="display:none;background-color:#74b9ff">
                                                                     </div>
                                                                     </div>

Comment: Your html code is hidden, because you didn't follow the [formatting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).  I have edited your question for you - you can delete your (now unnecessary) comments